# How to set properly the record source and pass the query parameter to load data into subform?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Scrapped this project and rebuild it from scratch.
Thank you so much @june7 for the guidance

```
Dim db As DAO.Database

' Re-link the CSV Table
Set db = CurrentDb
On Error Resume Next:   db.TableDefs.Delete "tblImport":   On Error GoTo 0
db.TableDefs.Refresh
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblImport", _
    FileName:="C:\MyData.csv", HasFieldNames:=true
db.TableDefs.Refresh

' Perform the import
db.Execute "INSERT INTO someTable SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM tblImport " _
   & "WHERE NOT F1 IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')"
db.Close:   Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: The data coming in is of a different data type than what is acceptable for those boxes (or fields if they tie directly). At a guess assigning the ControlSource to be an empty string makes it string type.

Comment: Why not just bind form and textboxes in design? Why VBA?

Comment: Code is not assigning ControlSource, it is assigning Value. Should not get that error with UNBOUND controls. So if you have bound form and controls, just apply filter to form.

Comment: Setting Value of BOUND controls will either change data in existing record or, if on new record row, create new record.

Comment: @June7 appreciate your assistance. I inherited this database & it has to be set as such by means of VBA to load up all the data into the textboxes. The original author has data being loaded onto a few textboxes upon form load up, if the condition is not met then the operator has to press the button to load up the data via VBA from the table which is were my problem starts. thank you so much

Comment: I am confused. If you inherited working db, then why are you writing this code? It's now your db and nothing 'has' to be as it is. Do what you want with it. If what condition is not met? Code shown would load only one record. Again, form and controls would have to be UNBOUND. You have not clarified if this is the case.

Comment: @June7 apologies for the messiness. scrapped the whole approach. now I have hit another wall the record source is not loading any data into the subform when I pass the parameter...

Comment: I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I apply filter to form or report.